# Detect URL and Download content from it

Tags: c#

I have a page 'PageA' that has around 20 links on it. Each link leads to a different page.

How can I access all the links on PageA programmatically and then download each of the pages(20) as .mht?

Also is there any existing app that does that?

Comment: What's a "mht" document?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the links out of the page. This tends to be more robust than regular expressions.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("PageA.htm");  
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"]) 
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    //...
}
```

To only select hyper links with a particular pattern you would update the xpath expression you pass to the SelectNodes method. E.g.

```
.SelectNodes("//a[@href=\"abc.com/articles\""])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search all the links using a regular expression, then you use an instance of WebClient class to download the contents. Here's an example http://dotnetperls.com/scraping-html (I haven't tried it, just found in the Internet).

Hope it helps.